# User enters a number in a textbox and is redirected to another webpage based on the number entered using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, redirect

I am trying to create a textbox where a user can enter a number, click a button and be redirected to another webpage using PHP based on the number the user entered. I am not sure why this is not working. You can save the code below in a PHP file. If you have any ideas, please let me know. If you have another way for such redirection using javascript, jQuery, or another language, please let me know. Thanks much. Have a nice day. V.

```
<?php
$textboxdata = $_POST['textboxdata'];

if (isset($_POST['$textboxdata'])) {
    switch ($textboxdata)
    {
    case 1:
      header("Location: one.php");
      break;
    case 2:
      header("Location: two.php");
      break;
    case 5:
      header("Location: five.php");
      break;
    default:
      echo "Enter a number please.";
    }
}
?>

</head>
<body>

<FORM NAME ="form" METHOD ="post" ACTION = "">
<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" VALUE ="username" METHOD ="post" name="textboxdata" >
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "submit" VALUE = "Login">

</FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any reason we can't just high-jack the form submit and use window.location and use the same switch statement in javascript? I don't see why PHP needs to handle this.

Answer (score 5):

This has a dollar sign in it and will not evaluate to true:

```
if (isset($_POST['$textboxdata'])) {
```

It should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['textboxdata'])) {
```

You also probably want an integer value for the `$_POST` data, so change this:

```
$textboxdata = $_POST['textboxdata'];
```

To this:

```
$textboxdata = intval( $_POST['textboxdata']);
```

Because remember, the user can type **anything** into that box, not just numbers. You will probably want to look into more input sanitation down the road.

Finally, you want to `exit()` after all of those `header()` calls (and the `Location` value should be a complete URL, not a relative one). The reason you want to `exit()` is because you want the script to stop processing there.

```
header("Location: one.php");
exit();
```

Comment: If we're being this thorough, I believe it would also be a good idea to make sure he doesn't have any output before calling `header()`.

Comment: It appears she has a case to handle non-numeric inputs.

Comment: Good catch. As for the sanitation bit, the `default` case should handle it. No real need to cast/convert to integer or worry about invalid input here, but in general - absolutely.

Comment: This is true, `default` should catch the other cases, it was mostly for floating point inputs, which matches a case when converted to an integer, but not as a string. But I agree, the general principle of user-input sanitation is always important :)

Comment: Thank you very much. That was the bug I couldn't detect. :)

Comment: @Veronica - You're quite welcome! If my post answered your question, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is the issue:

```
if (isset($_POST['$textboxdata'])) {
```

Should be:

```
if (isset($_POST['textboxdata'])) {
```

Comment: Also, @Veronica should test to see if `$_POST['textboxdata']` is set *before* assigning it to `$textboxdata`.

Answer (score 2):

Well seeing that you assign the `$_POST['textboxdata'];` to `$textboxdata` I would make it

```
$textboxdata = $_POST['textboxdata']; 

if (isset($textboxdata)) { 
    switch ($textboxdata)
```

If `$textboxdata`  is not set through the initial assignment then it will not hit the switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

> If you have another way for such redirection using javascript, jQuery,
>   or another language, please let me know.

jQuery solution:

```
<input type="text" value="username" id="inpt" />
<input type="button" value="login" id="btn" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#btn").on('click', function() {
            var value = $("#inpt").val();
            if (value.length) {
                switch (parseInt(value, 10)) {
                    case 1:
                      document.location.href = "one.php";
                      break;
                    case 2:
                      document.location.href = "two.php";
                      break;
                    case 5:
                      document.location.href = "five.php";
                      break;
                    default:
                      alert("Enter a number please.");
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```